# recursive header files situation

Tags: c++, coding-style

Writting my own project lead me to use someone's else piece of code to shorten time. It works and gets the job done, but running Doxygen over the entire project reveals a lot of headers files beeing called by several others files.

Just a example: file01.hpp includes file02.hpp wich includes file03.hpp that's also included by file012.cpp and file024.cpp.

I realize that those headers are really needed by the .cpp file but i'm pretty sure that it's usage can optimized.

My question can be divided in two parts:

1. Can i avoid those recursive calls or redundant headers, and if so how ?
2. Is there any tool freeware or open-source that i can use to see where those files are really needed or not ?

Comment: If you use include guards, it won't matter compilation wise. It'd only be eye candy

Comment: @Bettorun that i realize, but when you need to generate documentation for an entire project i see the graphs you certainly would like to improve the overall aspect....

Comment: All files should be independently compilable. Each should include all of it's dependencies even if this results in repetition. It really sucks when your program fails to compile because Z.h left out some includes that now must be included before Z.h can be included. So if A.h includes b.h and c.h even though b.h includes c.h, a.h is still consistent after the requirement for c.h is removed from b.h.